# Continuity at a single point implies continuity at the whole domain for a given function.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $f:(0, \infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that
$$f(x)=f\bigg(\frac{x}2+1\bigg).$$
Show that there exists a $p\in (0, \infty)$ such that if $f$ is continuous at $p$, then $f$ is continuous everywhere.

My idea: I started by noticing that
$$x=\frac{x}{2}+1\implies x=2.$$
I want to show that if $f$ is continuous at $2$, then $f$ is continuous everywhere.

Am I right? How to proceed if $p=2$?

Comment: The problem does not state that $x=\frac{x}{2}+1$. Also, you should not be trying to solve for $x$. The equation $f(x)=f\Bigl(\frac{x}{2}+1\Bigr)$ is supposed to hold for all $x\in (0,\infty)$.

Comment: Hint: for any $x$, the sequence defined by $x_0=x$ and $x_{n+1}=1+\frac{x_n}2$ converges to $2$. So, if $f$ is continuous at $p:=2$ then...

Comment: @jwhite yes but to look at that point p, I solved like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any $x\in(0,\infty)$, a closed form for the sequence $(a_n(x))$ defined by $a_0(x)=x$ and $a_{n+1}(x)=1+\frac{a_n(x)}2$ is $a_n(x)=2+\frac{x-2}{2^n}$, which converges to $2$. Moreover, on this sequence, $f$ is constantly equal to $f(x)$. So, if $f$ is continuous at $p:=2$ then $$\forall x\in(0,\infty),\quad f(2)=f(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n(x))=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n(x))=f(x),$$ i.e. $f$ is constant.